# Zip cycle list, which way is efficient?

Tags: haskell

As an example, given a list `xs = [1..10]`, the thing I want is:

```
[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7),(7,8),(8,9),(9,10),(10,1)]
```

my solution is

```
zip xs (tail xs ++ [head xs])     -- solution (1)
```

and someone suggests that

```
zip xs (tail . cycle $ xs)        -- solution (2)
```

but I don't know whether the solution (2) is more efficient? or two solutions are equivalent?

Comment: Have you tried timing the two methods and seeing for yourself?

Comment: @AJFarmar I have not learned how to timing the Haskell program.

Comment: I would expect these solutions to be similar in performance. One could try the `criterion` library to benchmark them. http://www.serpentine.com/criterion/

Comment: @chi Thank you very much. I shall try it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unexpected! Solution (1) is faster. I just test it using GHC Runtime System statistics. The test case is `[1..10^7]`, here is code:

Solution (1):

```
xs   = [1..10^7]
main = print $ last $ zip xs (tail xs ++ [head xs])
```

Solution (2):

```
xs   = [1..10^7]
main = print $ last $ zip xs (tail . cycle $ xs )
```

Compile option:

```
ghc -O2 -rtsopts ZipCycleList1.hs
```

Run option:

```
ZipCycleList1.exe +RTS -s
```

Result of Solution (1):

```
   1,520,081,768 bytes allocated in the heap
         603,912 bytes copied during GC
          42,960 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
          26,672 bytes maximum slop
               2 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      1459 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.004s     0.0000s    0.0006s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0001s    0.0002s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.312s  (  0.305s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.000s  (  0.004s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.312s  (  0.310s elapsed)

  %GC     time       0.0%  (1.3% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    4,872,025,717 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity 100.0% of total user, 98.5% of total elapsed
```

Result of Solution (2):

```
   1,520,081,832 bytes allocated in the heap
     992,426,304 bytes copied during GC
     250,935,040 bytes maximum residency (12 sample(s))
      42,981,632 bytes maximum slop
             569 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      1449 colls,     0 par    0.296s   0.301s     0.0002s    0.0006s
  Gen  1        12 colls,     0 par    0.406s   0.622s     0.0518s    0.2284s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.328s  (  0.305s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.702s  (  0.922s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    1.030s  (  1.228s elapsed)

  %GC     time      68.2%  (75.1% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    4,640,024,688 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  31.8% of total user, 24.9% of total elapsed
```

Answer (score 1):

My intuition is that they will have identical performance. If you prefer an empirical answer to one based on experience, then you should build yourself a small benchmark; the criterion or timeit packages are popular choices here. Be sure to compile and use `-O2`, because the interpreter has famously unreliable performance and GHC's optimizer is very clever.